# Vertical Graph Bars in JSP

Tags: html, css, jsp, graph, html-table

I have a jsp page in which there is a horizontal graph bars generating dynamically in table.
I have no idea if I can make the graph bars vertically.
Need a help if we can make the bars vertical through CSS.

Can anyone guide me how can I work on this?

Here is a code for reference. If this can help.

```
<logic:greaterThan name="size" value="0">
    <table border="0" width="100%" align="left">
        <tr><td></td><td></td><td><font face="Verdana" size="10" color="#333399"><%=request.getAttribute("header")%></font></td></tr>
        <tr><td  height="120"></td><td></td><td valign="top" align="left"><hr width ="320"></td></tr>

        <logic:iterate id="dayEntry" name="LeaveForm" property="results">
            <tr>
                <td align="right" width="20%"></td>
                <td align="right" width="10%">
                    <bean:write name="dayEntry" property="month"/>
                </td>
                <td align="left" width="80%">
                    <table width='<bean:write name="dayEntry" property="percent"/>%' bgcolor='<bean:write name="dayEntry" property="color"/>' title='<bean:write name="dayEntry" property="date"/>'>
                        <tr>
                            <td align="right">
                                <font color="white">
                                        <bean:write name="dayEntry" property="days"/>
                                </font>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </logic:iterate>
    <tr><td height="40"></td></tr>
</table>
            </logic:greaterThan>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `transform` from CSS3.